# Is it possible to make fonts fuzzy, like in a bad scan?

Tags: fonts, pdf

Are there any LaTeX technologies that could allow to simulate a poorly-scanned document, such as fuzzy fonts? I imagine that rotating odd and even pages slightly should not be too difficult, but the fuzzy looking fonts baffle me.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/401032/can-gaussian-or-similar-blur-be-applied-to-tikz-text  An easier solution is to run the document through an image processing program.